# PDE (heat equation type) with strange boundary value behaviour

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I have the following PDE:

$$u_t=u_{xx}$$

**EDIT (Because I was not clear):**
The boundary conditions can be stated in two versions. In general it is known that the solution is symmetric in $x$ and we know that $u(x=1,t)=0$. 
So the boundary conditions can be stated as version 1:
$$u(x=1,t)=0 \qquad \text {and} \qquad u_x(x=0,t)=0.$$

Now, by the symmetry in $x$ it is also true that $u(x=-1,t)=0$. So the second version of boundary condtions can be stated as:
$$u(x=1,t)=0 \qquad \text {and} \qquad u(x=-1,t)=0.$$

If I apply method of separation $u=T(t)X(x)$, I will get the following system of ODEs:

$$T'(t)/T(t)=-k^2 \qquad X''(x)/X(x)=-k^2.$$

These have the general solutions:

$$T(t)=T_0\mathrm{e}^{-k^2t} \qquad X(x)=a\sin(kx)+b\cos(kx).$$

---

**Now, here comes the strange thing (different solutions depending on what solution "path" I take and which boundary condition version I use).**

If I use $u(x=\pm1,t)=0$, I get $X(x=\pm1)=0$:

$$0=a\sin(k)+b\cos(k) \qquad 0=-a\sin(k)+b\cos(k)$$

Adding both equations gives:
$0=b\cos(k) \implies b = 0$ or $k=\pi+\pi l$, with $l\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Considering $b=0$: This can imply $a=0$, which leads to a trivial solution, but it can also lead to a consistent result for $k=\pi l$, in which $l\in \mathbb{Z}$.

How is it possible, that there are the two different solutions?
$$X(x)=a\sin(\pi l x) \text{     or    } X(x)=b\cos((\pi/2+\pi l)x) $$

I would be glad if someone could point out my mistake.

---

It is interessting to note, that the boundary conditions $u(x=1,t)$ and $u_x(x=0,t)=0$ lead to one answer only.

**Why does it matter which boundary conditions I use? And how can I know that I am using the right conditions?**

Comment: What do you mean by strange? Because the solution is not unique?

Comment: Yes, how can I decide from my physical problem which solution is correct?

Comment: Where did you use the condition $u_x(0, t) = 0$?

Comment: I didn't write the calculations but if you use $u(1,t)=u'(0,t)=0$. The solution is unique.

Comment: @FelixMarin: How do you come up with that?

Comment: @MrYouMath It satisfies the differential equation and the boundary conditions.

Comment: @FelixMarin: That is clear, but it is a trivial solution there are non-trivial solutions.

Comment: It seems to me like your question is missing some context. You provided the boundary conditions and you know there's a unique solution, but you are not satisfied?

Comment: @JackyChong: By the solution manual I know the solution should be given as a linear combination of $\cos((\pi/2+\pi l)x)$ scaled with an exponential function. But I want to understand how, different BC (of the same function) can lead to different solutions. I will try to improve my question.

Comment: What do you mean the same function with different BC? Do you means same equation with different BC?

Comment: @JackChong: From the physical situation I know that the function is symmetric in $x$. From this I can state $u(x=\pm1,t)=0$ or $u(x=1,t)=u_x(x=0,t)$. But the first condition leads to two different solutions, while the first expression leads to one solution only.

Comment: For you first BC, you are basically nailing down the waves at two points. Whereas, the second BC, you are nailing down the wave at one point and not feeding any "energy" on the other end point.

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer a more structured approach to your problem. Than you may see what is weird about it.

We note that the equation is constant coefficient and posed on $\mathbb{R}_t \times [-1,1]_x$. This shows that is possible to use the Fourier transform (in $t$) to reduce the problem to the following ODE:
$$i\tau\hat{u} = \hat{u}_{xx},\\\hat{u}(\tau,\pm1) = 0.$$
Using integration by parts we see that the operator $\partial_{xx}$ with domain $C^\infty([-1,1])$ is self-adjoint on $L^2([-1,1])$. This implies that the spectrum is contained in the reals, that is the equation above has only the trivial solution for $\tau \in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$. For $\tau = 0$ we know that $u$ must be linear and the boundary conditions demand that it is zero.

The problem is that you do not impose initial conditions for $t=t_0$. Then you would get the usual heat equation on the domain $[-1,1]$ with Dirichlet boundary condition. So if you start with some $u(t_0) = u_0$ in some reasonable space (say $C^0_0 = \{f \in C^0\,|\, f(\pm 1) = 0\}$) then you get a unique solution which is not zero. But: You can only solve for $t > t_0$.

The case of the initial value (in $x$) problem (for completeness): Let $\alpha_{\pm} = \frac{1 \pm i}{\sqrt 2}$ and note that $\alpha_{\pm}^2 = i$. Then the general solution to our equation is given by
$$\hat{u}(\tau, x) = c_1 e^{\alpha_+ \sqrt \tau x} + c_2 e^{\alpha_- \sqrt \tau x}.$$
So, we see that you have to many boundary conditions (three for two unknowns) and i guess (haven't checked it) you have some additional condition such that you can take the inverse fourier transform (because the real part of the exponential is non-zero).

Comment: 1+: For your efforts. Sorry, but that is not quite what I was intending to say. The bc are $u(t,x=\pm1)=0$ or $u(t,x=1)=0$ and $u_x(t,x=0)=0$ (See my edit in my question for the boundary conditions).